# in the coming days or in the next following days

Tags: grammar

My assignments will be due on April 24. I want to write to my professor that "I will try my best to do my assignments in the next following days." Or," I will work harder on my assignments in the coming days."
Which one is better?
Thank you.

Comment: "next following" is a tautology - the words *next* and *following* have the same meaning. Everything that is "following" is next. However, even with the correction, "... in the next days" and "... in the following days" are not idiomatic.